# Google Analytic's, Regex, регулярные выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, google-analytics

Добрый день, возникла проблема с GA и регулярными выражениями. Никак немогу найти подходящию регулярку фильтра, для того что бы показать report по посещениям только по определенным URL. Приходило пока в голову только сделать регулярку которая захватывает 3символа "/", но это походу неработает

Пример страниц:

- zahrada/
- zahrada/okrasná zahrada/
- zahrada/uzitkova-zahrada/
- zahrada/pokojove-rostliny/
- zahrada/choroby-a-skudci/
- zahrada/zahradni-technika/
- zahrada/zahradni-stavby/

Comment: попробовал использовать только ^/zahrada/$ в фильтре показывает только стату по первому url, /zahrada/

Comment: `$` уберите из фильтра.

Comment: если уберать то тогда фильтр показывает все страницы, а мне нужен только путь до второго слеша, то есть без страницы которая подкреплена к  заданным url

Comment: если оставлять $ то показывает только /zahrada/, а нужны остальные тоже

Comment: `^/zahrada/[^/]+/$` ?

Comment: пробовал, тогда пропадает из списка /zahrada/ просто.

Comment: В списке остаются все остальные пути с двумя папками? Если да, то `^/zahrada/([^/]+/)?$` используйте.

Comment: как бы так сказать, эта регулярка поидеи работает, но кроме этих страниц которые я указывал выше показываются еще например вот такие /zahrada/hrach, но я бы нехотел их в списке репорта, хотелось бы только 7 выше указанных. Спасибо что тратите и свое время на мою проблему

Comment: Я так и не понял, регулярка `^/zahrada/([^/]+/)?$` сработала или нет? И если сработала, то что лишнее выдала или недодала?

Comment: да сработала, показывает уже /zahrada/ тоже, но выдает лишнию инфу такую как-  /zahrada/hrach и тд и тп.@visman

Comment: Странно это все. Может слэш стоит экранировать `^\/zahrada\/([^\/]+\/)?$`, хотя у них в документации про него ни чего не говорится. Можно конечно попробовать прямым перечислением сделать: `^/zahrada/((okrasná zahrada|uzitkova\-zahrada|pokojove\-rostliny|choroby\-a\-skudci|zahradni\-technika|zahradni\-stavby)/)?$`, но длинно сильно.

Comment: Да согласен, ну значет буду использовать такой длинный фильтр иначне другими путями показывает инфу по другим url.
Спасибо @Visman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> показать report по посещениям **только по определенным URL**

Если есть конкретные URL, невозможно использовать общие шаблоны типа символьных классов, нужно использовать группы (подмаски) с чередованием возможных значений (т.е. `(значение1|значение2|...|значениеN)`).

Чтобы уменьшить вычислительную нагрузку, можно использовать вложенные группы.

Можно воспользоваться следующим шаблоном:

```
^/zahrada/(((okrasná |uzitkova-)zahrada|pokojove-rostliny|choroby-a-skudci|zahradni-(technika|stavby))/)?$
```

[Демо на regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gP3gO5/1).

Ни один из символов в этом регулярном выражении для GA не нуждается в экранировании.

**Дополнительная информация о шаблоне**:

- `^` -
- `/zahrada/` - текст `/zahrada/`
- `(` - опциональная подмаска

  - `(` - одно из следующих значений:

    - `(okrasná |uzitkova-)zahrada` - `okrasná zahrada` или `uzitkova-zahrada`
    - `|pokojove-rostliny` - или `pokojove-rostliny`
    - `|choroby-a-skudci` - или `choroby-a-skudci`
    - `|zahradni-(technika|stavby)` - или zahradni-technika`или`zahradni-stavby`
  - `)` - конец обязательной подмаски
- `/` - символ `/`
- `)?` - конец необязательной подмаски
- `$` - конец строки